# Broadcasting in socket.io?

Tags: socket.io, broadcasting

How to broadcast a message among all the connected clients in socket.io?

I am using mrniko/netty-cosket.io server with with java (play/eclipse) on server side and socket.io.js 0.9 on client side. Both client & server working fine (i.e. sending and receiving messages). To keep the records of the connected clients , I am using hashMaps and to send a message to all connected users I am iterating the hashmap and sending messages one by one. just wanna know is there any better way to send messages to all connected clients at once?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code:

```
//broadcasts to all clients connected
io.sockets.emit('function', {foo:bar});

//broadcasts to all clients connected, except the sender
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('function', {foo:bar}); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example in case of mrniko/netty-socket.io usage:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setHostname("localhost");
    config.setPort(9092);

SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);

BroadcastOperations bo = server.getBroadcastOperations();
// every method will broadcast messages to all server clients
bo.sendJsonObject(...)

server.start();
...
```

Comment: Thanks Nikita For your kind help :)